# $|a+b| \leq |a-b|$ if $a<0<b$ .What is the proof?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$|a-b|$: is the distance between $a$ and $b$

$|a+b|$: is the distance between "$a+b$" and $0$.

What is the algebraic proof?

Comment: What is an algorithmic proof and how does it differ from a non-algorithmic proof?

Comment: different from a geometric proof

Comment: Then you mean an *algebraic* proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $a < 0 < b$, we have
$$4ab<0 \implies (a+b)^2 - (a-b)^2 < 0 \implies (a+b)^2 < (a-b)^2 \implies \vert a+b \vert < \vert a-b \vert$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's introduce $k = -a > 0$ for convenience.

Then $|a - b| = |-k -b| = k + b$.  At the same time, $|a+b| = |b - k|$ is equal to either $ b - k$, or $k-b$, which in any case is obviously less than $k+b$.

Answer (score 1):

Square both sides: $|a+b|^2 \leq |a-b|^2 \Leftarrow a^2+2ab+b^2 \leq a^2-2ab+b^2 \Leftarrow 4ab \leq 0$ which is true since $a < 0 < b$.

Comment: You should use the backward direction.

Comment: you should change $\rightarrow$ to $\leftrightarrow$ otherwise you are assuming that $|a+b| \leq |a-b|$ and you are in fact proving that this implies that $a$ and $b$ must have opposite signs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $$|a-b|=|b-a|=\bigl||b|+|a|\bigr|=|b|+|a|=|a|+|b|,$$ so by [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), the result follows immediately.